Wrong total width and height when multiple objects selected
In the following screenshot, there are 3 squares each of dimension 50px x 50px.
When I select the 3 objects, in the transform pane, it shows totally wrong width of 12283.4313px and height of 67.3556px.
The correct dimensions should be 150px width & 50px height when the 3 are selected.
Is this a bug? or there's something I can do to fix this?
I'm using Adobe Illustrator 24.4.1.


You are right, the problem that there's a guide selected and I didn't notice it. Thank you
